# TFS 2013 Build: Which process retrieves the build process template?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently trying to set up a build machine for continuous integration.

Our TFS project collection resides on one machine (TFSServer), while we've installed the build service, controller and agents on a different machine (TFSBuild).

When I queue a build, I get the following error:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
...
```

This seems to happen when the controller? tries to retrieve the build process template from the TFS server.

The inner exception is the following:

```
Exception Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080 (type SocketException)
...
```

This is where I get confused, because a connection to `localhost` was attempted. I would've expected that the call be made to TFSServer instead.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or should I look in a different direction to solve my issue?

**Edit**: I have this feeling that the problem is caused because I had initially installed TFS Server on the build machine, and that some cached value points to the localhost server which used to exist, but not anymore...

**Edit 2**: I was not able to set up a controller on the build machine, for some reason it keeps looking for the build process template locally instead of the TFS server. So instead, I set up the controller on the TFS server, and the agents on the build machine and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your build service might be still pointing to previous TFS server URL which was installed on the same build server. You can check this setting by launching **TFS Administration Console** and clicking **Build configuration**, then update it to point to the Team Project Collection configured on another box.

Comment: I'm assuming that it's already pointing to the right collection since I can queue builds from visual studio. I can also see activity in the console when I do, next to the controller (something like "build started").